# Type Error when trying Stack Navigator from React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm running the example below locally but get a TypeError.

```
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import SecoundScreen from './screens/SecoundScreen';
import ThirdScreen from './screens/ThirdScreen';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Second" component={SecoundScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Third" component={ThirdScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MyStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

[image: Type Error]

I copied the from the example, and it didn't work before I modified it either @ https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=createStackNavigator%20%C2%B7%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%40%5E5.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.0.0%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%401.5.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%401.4.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%400.6.0%2Creact-native-screens%402.0.0-alpha.12&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fsimple-stack.js

The code below is working! I just installed react-navigation, so I should have the latest version!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';

import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import SecondScreen from './screens/SecondScreen';
import ThirdScreen from './screens/ThirdScreen';


import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomeScreen,
        Second: SecondScreen,
        Third: ThirdScreen
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
);
export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Any idea why the first version is failing?

package.json before and after npm update:

```
  {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
    "react-navigation-fluid-transitions": "^0.3.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: I think `"@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.0"` is missing in your package.json. Add it then run `npm install --save` and then try to run your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update the dependencies, this did the trick:

`$ npm install -g npm-check-updates
$ npm-check-updates -u
$ npm install`